# HttpServletRequest.getSession(true) thread safe?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I see a lot of questions concerning whether the setAttribute and getAttribute methods on `HttpSession` are atomic. They are not. But, is the actual call of `request.getSession(true)` atomic per client?

For example if you had a servlet filter and a client issue two simultaneous calls which simultaneously reach a line `request.getSession(true)` would the same session object be returned? I assume such a thing would be container specific? Or are you gauranteed a syncronized `getSession` call per requesting client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are really concerned here:

> For example if you had a servlet filter, and a client issues two
>   simultaneous calls which simultaneously reach the line:
>
> `request.getSession(true)`
>
> would the same session object be returned?

It depends on what you mean by *same session object*, ie if you mean `s1 == s2` or `s1.equals(s2)`. I can't find anything stating that the object must be the same (`==`), but even if likely they are all different objects, they eventually *can see* the same *logical* session. Imagine these session objects as database clients: they are not *the data*, but they all *view* the same data, ie they read and write to a common place.

Now, to answer your question, we must decide if the client issued the second request before reading any other response from the same server: a session must be tracked with a piece of input (either in the URL or in the HTTP headers, in the form of a cookie), so we have the following scenarios:

1. Client makes request #1, gets a session, and sends the session ID back to the server in two simultaneous requests #2 and #3: they will share the session
2. Client makes request #1 and #2 almost at the same time, without any previous request to the same application. Since no input is provided to the server (no session ID) two new sessions are created, even if the clients **don't hit the getSession() line at the same moment**. Depending on the client application, this may be a bug or not.

So this is not a problem with threads at all. It just depends on the input supplied by the client. Same session ID, same session returned. Different (or no) session ID, different sessions.

Just for the sake of correctness, a *logical* client (a single program, like Firefox) can even make N requests in N separate threads on a N+ cores machine, but the network is usually shared. Assuming it has a multihomed machine, and each NIC is connected to a separate network, you'll need your servlet container to listen to multiple IP addresses and have N processors (or cores). This is just to say that there's no need to have two *simultaneous calls*, though it's perfectly possible that requests from the same client are processed in parallel and thus reach the same line at the same moment.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not.

**Servlet Spec says...**

> 2.3.3.4 Thread Safety
>   Other than the startAsync and complete methods, implementations of the request and response objects are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This means that they should either only be used within the scope of the request handling thread or the application must ensure that access to the request and response objects are thread safe.
>   
> If a thread created by the application uses the container-managed objects, such as the request or response object, those objects must be accessed only within the object’s life cycle as defined in sections 3.10 and 5.6. **Be aware that other than the startAsync, and complete methods, the request and response objects are not thread safe.If those objects were accessed in the multiple threads, the access should be synchronized or be done through a wrapper to add the thread safety, for instance, synchronizing the call of the methods to access the request attribute, or using a local output stream for the response object within a thread.**

And to your question? 
**Is it possible that two concurrent calls to getSession return a different HttpSession object even they come from the same client?** 
The answer is "Yes,

- it will return two session objects,
- two Set-Cookies Will be sent to the client
- The latest Set-Cookie might override the first one

Comment: is nt that about Request and Response objects. Question was about Session right?

Comment: That concerns the request and response object. I am specifically asking about request.getSession(). The actual session that is returned, is it possible that two concurrent calls to getSession return a different HttpSession object even they come from the same client? Or, does one request invalidate the other in that case?

Comment: @MatthewKirkley Please read the bold words. It means that other than startAsync() , request and response objects are not thread sage. If request and response objects are not thread safe, it is common sense that the methods are not thread safe. Please try to read the answers with patience and then downvote.

Comment: Updated my answer in detail.

Comment: `If request and response objects are not thread safe, it is common sense that the methods are not thread safe.`? I am not really sure, what if these objects have synchronized methods.?getSession() may not be thread safe and same object is visible to multiple threads. But what if getAttribute and setAttribute is synchronized

Comment: That snippet from the servlet spec doesn't allow you to deduce the a call to getSession is not syncronized

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29) suggests that the method is synchronized, though I don't know what is going on inside the method. Doing `getSession(true)` returns a new session if one doesn't exist. The check for an existing session and the creation of a new one is your critical section. If that is reached simultaneously by your threads, then two sessions will have been created and returned to your two different calling entities (filters will be applied before and, possibly, after your servlets so I don't see how you can do this, but for the question's sake let's assume it can happen). If a `Session` object already exists, then only that one will be returned.