# Is this servlet thread safe?

Tags: java, servlets

I have passed the `HttpServletRequest` to another method in the servlet. Could I keep the servlet thread-safe? Is the below code thread-safe with `er()` method?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.getWriter().append("Your session Id: ").append(er(request));
}

public String er(HttpServletRequest request){
    return request.getSession().getId();
}
```

Comment: There is no question on thread safety in your code, because it all runs on the  same thread, and there's no other thread in sight.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos It's a Servlet. They are inherently multithreaded.

Comment: @EJP. of course. But this code does not have any possible thread dependencies. `HttpServletRequest` is generated per-request, which in the default model means per-thread. The session might conceptually be shared across threads if multiple requests are active, but that is irrelevant here because we care about the sesion ID, and that's the container's responsibility.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Unless any wait() call are not occured, all codes go the same thread? even if er() is outside of the doGet() method?

Answer (score 1):

it is perfectly fine, you are not modifying any state within the Servlet itself, the servlet lifecycle creates one instance of the servlet and calls the `init()` method, any additional requests come through the same instance. so if you don't have any unprotected instance variables, you should be fine.

Comment: The servlet container itself has state which may be modified by the getSession() call

Answer (score -1):

Because `request.getSession()` optionally creates a session, the answer is that you may have a race condition where to "simultaneous" calls from the same client may result in different session objects created for that client and consequently, different IDs returned.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139753/httpservletrequest-getsessiontrue-thread-safe)